# JDBC/Oracle insert NULL without preparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a very confusing problem I don't understand.
I am building INSERT statements for different tables and execute them as Batch at the end.

The Statements are build like this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('anyValue', 'anyValue', 'anyValue', ...)
```

The table definition doesn't contain only varchar, there are number, float and timestamp also, but it doesn't matter at all because Oracle makes a type conversion by itself

**BUT...**
If I try to insert NULL in a NUMBER it says invalid number, but for example in PLSQL developer it works like a charm. Looks like this:

`INSERT INTO table (varchar, varchar, number, ...) VALUES ('value', 'value', NULL, ...)` <- doesnt work, but why?

I am using Oracle11g database with the ojdbc6.jar library.
I know the Syntax above is not correct, but it's just to clarify the types and what I try to insert.

Is there any solution to this, **without** using preparedStatement and setNull(), because I don't know the field types at runtime

**EDIT**

```
INSERT ALL  INTO comediatypeadjustments VALUES('1','TEST','1','DEL_COC_361','DEL_COC_361','100','Y','Y','N','GREEN','Y','Y','N','N','LIGHTGREEN','STD','10.65','STD','55.25','N','N',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'N',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'N',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Y','WHITE','STD_BOLD_UL','44.25',NULL,NULL,'N','N','N',NULL,'N',NULL,'N',NULL,'N',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Y','N') INTO comediatypeadjustments VALUES('2','TEST','2','DEL_COC_362','DEL_COC_362','100','Y','Y','N','BLUE','Y','Y','N','N','LIGHTGREEN','STD','10.65','STD','55.25','N','N',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'N',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'N',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Y','WHITE','STD_BOLD_UL','44.25',NULL,NULL,'N','N','N',NULL,'N',NULL,'N',NULL,'N',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Y','N') SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Fehler bei
>   Stapelverarbeitung aufgetreten: ORA-01722: invalid number
>
> at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeBatch(OracleStatement.java:4586)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
>     at
>   de.draexlmaier.pcm.test.testcase.TestCaseHelper.initializeTestData(TestCaseHelper.java:285)
>     at
>   de.draexlmaier.pcm.test.testcase.TestCaseHelper.setTestName(TestCaseHelper.java:118)
>     at de.draexlmaier.pcm.test.utilities.Main.main(Main.java:19)

Comment: Show us your **real** statement that generates the error, and add the _complete_ error message you get. **Edit** your question, don't post code in comments. If I had to guess: you are trying to put a character value into a number column - but without the real query this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Have you tried `'NULL'`?

Comment: @Fildor I sincerely hope not, as it is nonsense. A more pertinent question would be whether the OP has actually tried `NULL`, without any quotes. Impossible to say from the incomplete evidence he has posted.

Comment: no, didn't try it yet, because Oracle would treat it like a varchar, I guess? ... You are wrong: I try to insert NULL into a number column.

Comment: Why do you list the same column twice, and why is it named `varchar`? --- Anyway, to insert NULL, don't mention it: `INSERT INTO table (varchar, varchar, ...) VALUES ('value', 'value', ...)`. The `number` column will now have default value, which is usually NULL.

Comment: @EJP Ooops, number col. Sorry, missed that.

Comment: You didn't read my post carefully: They are not the column names, they are the column types...
I know that too, but I can't select the columns which doesn't have NULL as value, because I only get the values to insert for every column .. I dont know the column names

Comment: Since you are using Java, iguess there will be some mapping issue with the column and the inserted value. Please specify column names first and then put values like insert into <table>(column_1,column_2,column_3,...) values(val1,val2,val3...)

Comment: How can you *not* know the column names but know the table name? And why use `insert all`. What's wrong with a good old plain single row `insert` statement? Also: numbers should **not** be specified with single quotes. `'55.25'` is a character literal, not a number.

Comment: Plus: you _can_ insert null values without knowing the data type using a `PreparedStatement`:  `pstmt.setObject(2, null);` works just fine with the Oracle driver (although it _is_ a bit slower than using `setNull()`)

Comment: Because I need to implement a INSERT Statement and I only get the table name as a String and the values as a List of Strings ... I cant diff between the column types because I dont know the table Definition ... I don't see what a single INSERT would change?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Java, I guess there will be some mapping issues with the columns and the inserted values. Please specify column names first and then put values like

```
insert into <table>(column_1,column_2,column_3,...) values(val1,val2,val3...);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try empty string '', oracle db will treat it as null.

Comment: You're kidding. Oracle will treat a string literal as a number with null value? Evidence?